# MYSQL Select single row by multiple parameters returning unexpected result

Tags: mysql

I have a table `offers` with five relevant columns, `offer_id`, `offer_type`, `offer_amount`, `end_date` and `offer_status`

I am trying to select the row with the highest `offer_amount` that matches the correct `offer_type` and an `offer_status` of 1 (active).

The query I am using is

`SELECT * FROM offers_tbl WHERE offer_status = 1 AND offer_type = 'site-wide' AND offer_amount = (SELECT MAX(offer_amount) FROM offers_tbl )`

Whats happening is that this is not returning any results if the MAX(offer_amount) happens to have a `offer_status` of 0 (inactive).

If the particular row with the highest `MAX(offer_amount)` happens to have an offer_status of 1, this works fine. Its only when the offer status is 0 that this breaks.

Comment: is there only the amount as reletion between offer_status and offer_amount tables or is there also a id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making it find MAX out of active ones:

`SELECT * FROM offers_tbl WHERE offer_status = 1 AND offer_type = 'site-wide' AND offer_amount = (SELECT MAX(offer_amount) FROM offers_tbl WHERE offer_status = 1)`

Otherwise, it's finding MAX offer amounts that could have a status of 0, which makes the outside query not find a match of status of 1 AND that amount.

Comment: PERFECT! I knew it was something like that. Thanks! As soon as I Can accept your answer, I will